# Matrix of Discrete fourier transform $F^4$ is identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fourier-analysis

I already showed that Discrete fourier transform matrix is unitarian matrix. Now I would like to show that $F^4$ is identity.
On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_fourier_transform#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) is written:

> "This can be seen from the inverse properties above: operating  twice
>   gives the original data in reverse order, so operating  four times
>   gives back the original data and is thus the identity matrix."

I don't see very well this reverse order. And even if it gives the original data in reverse order that doesn't meen that next time it will give data in original order. Is it possible to prove this other way ?
Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You are misunderstanding. Start with a (row) vector $\mathbf x$. Then, $\mathbf xF$ is the DFT $\mathbf X$, and the claim is that $\mathbf XF = \mathbf xF^2$ gives you $\mathbf x$ in _reverse_ order, that is, the $i$-th element of $\hat{\mathbf x} = \mathbf xF^2$ is $\hat{x}_i = x_{N-i}$. If you apply $F$ twice more to $\hat{\mathbf x} = \mathbf xF^2$, you will get another vector $\tilde{\mathbf x}=\hat{\mathbf x}F^2=\mathbf xF^4$ whose $i$-th element is $$\tilde{x}_i = \hat{x}_{N-i} = x_{N-(N-i)} = x_i,$$ that is, the second reversal of order restores the data to their original order.