# How many repeated applications of a reflection matrix is required to get back to starting vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

I have recently understood that orthongonal matrices actually perform reflection, not rotation, if the determinent is non unity. The question is, if that is the case, then why does it require **4** repeated applications of DFT matrix to get unity matrix? Notice DFT matrix has no unity determinant at least if the size is odd. If it is doing reflection, then **two** applications of the matrix should results in identity. How do you interpret that?

Comment: DFT's are complex matrices. Unlike real orthogonal matrices, where the determinant is 1 or -1, the determinant of complex unitary matrices can be a complex number $|z| =1$. E.g. if $z=i$ then $z^4=1$, but $z^2=-1$.

Comment: @Mick does this mean that only if determinant is strictly (-1), we say there's reflection?

Comment: It is more accurate to say that orthogonal matrices with determinant $-1$ are rotations with reflections. This does not necessarily mean that the square of the matrix is the identity matrix. Although if this particular matrix is also symmetric then its square is the identity mtx.

Comment: @Mick any intuition for why exactly 4 repetitions of DFT matrices returns the identity?

Comment: Well write a 2x2 general dft matrix and look at its powers. Do you notice something?

Comment: @Mick going back to your second point, I managed to interpret it. The orthogonal matrix is ROTATING THEN REFLECTING, the reflection is done by multiplying the basis by (not a negative number), but rather imaginary, thus, it takes 4 replication of this to return to first point. Thanks.

Comment: See the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/362695)

Comment: @JeanMarie Yeah, I know that phenomenon. I just can't get geometrical intuition whenever complex numbers are involved. Thank you Jean.